# URL not redirecting in iOS webviews on Corona SDK

Tags: ios, uiwebview, coronasdk

In Corona SDK, I have a webview that shows an advertisement.

It works perfectly in Android, but in iOS the URLs is not clicking or redirecting.

This is an URL sample

```
<a href="close://"><img src="btn_cancel.png" /></a>
```

This doesn't click or redirect in iOS webviews.

I need the return of the event listener of my webview `event.url` and it should return "`close://`"

so I can trigger my condition

```
function iosWebListener( event )
    if event.type == "loaded" then
        if 1 == string.find( event.url, "close://" ) then
             webView:removeSelf()
             webView = nil
        end
    end
end
```

Again this works perfectly in Android but not in iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my problem

This is what causing not to load the links, so I remove the condition.

```
if event.type == "loaded" then 
    ...
end
```

It doesn't seems to work on iOS but it works on Android